# Powershell issues with app pool restart schedule

Tags: powershell, iis

This is the first thing I have ever done with Powershell. The gist of the script is to do some base setup for my companies web server installation.  Basically it should

1. Take a list of names
2. Make a user with that name
3. configure user make a folder with that name
4. make an application pool with that name
5. set application pool properties
6. set folder permissions for a group

The code is below.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
#$apps = @('H','N1','N2')
foreach ($app in $apps){


    ## I need to check for if a user exists first
    NET USER $app "password" /ADD
    NET LOCALGROUP "iis_iusrs" $app  /ADD
    WMIC USERACCOUNT WHERE "Name=$app" SET PaswordExpires=False


    #See if the application's folder exists
    if (!(Test-Path("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\"+$app)))
    {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\$app
    }

       ## See if the application Pool exists. If it doesn't then create it
    if (!(Test-Path("IIS:\AppPools\"+$app)))
    {
        $appPool = New-Item ("IIS:\AppPools\"+$app)
        $appPool.ProcessModel.identityType = 3
        $appPool.ProcessModel.userName=$app
        $appPool.ProcessModel.password="password"
        $appPool.ProcessModel.idleTimeout=[TimeSpan]::FromMinutes(0)
        $appPool.processModel.loadUserProfile="True"
        $appPool.recycling.disallowOverlappingRotation = "True"
        $appPool.recycling.disallowRotationOnConfigChange = "True"
        $appPool.recycling.periodicRestart.time = [TimeSpan]::FromMinutes(0)


        $appPool | Set-Item
        $propPath = "IIS:\AppPools\"+$appPool
        New-ItemProperty -Path $propPath -Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule -Value @{value="00:06:00"}              

    }
}

$webserver =  Hostname
if(!(Test-Path("C:\"+$webserver)))
{
    $hostserver = Read-Host "What is the host server's name?"
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\$webserver\$hostserver
}

if(!(Test-Path('C:\Temp')))
{
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\Temp
}

$Acl_inetpub = Get-Acl C:\inetpub
$Acl_temp = Get-Acl C:\Temp
$Acl_windows_temp = Get-Acl C:\Windows\Temp


$Ar_iis = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(".\iis_iusrs","FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$Ar_users = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(".\users","FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")

$Acl_inetpub.SetAccessRule($Ar_iis)
$Acl_inetpub.SetAccessRule($Ar_users)

$Acl_temp.SetAccessRule($Ar_iis)
$Acl_temp.SetAccessRule($Ar_users)

$Acl_windows_temp.SetAccessRule($Ar_iis)
$Acl_windows_temp.SetAccessRule($Ar_users)

Set-Acl C:\inetpub $Acl_inetpub
Set-Acl C:\temp $Acl_temp
Set-Acl C:\Windows\Temp $Acl_windows_temp
```

My issue currently is.

```
    $propPath = "IIS:\AppPools\"+$appPool
    New-ItemProperty -Path $propPath -Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule -Value @{value="00:06:00"}
```

I get a path error when I run this but I am not sure where the error is coming from. Also, is there a way to do this same thing but just using the object like I did the rest of the settings? So far I have not found a way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried putting $propPath in between those 2 lines to see what path is echoed to the console?

Comment: yeah that led to my solution....I just had to look at it a few more times to see what was output.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the final issue thanks Randy Schuman's advice. I wasn't thinking about how I was using $app vs $appPool . I was just continuing the pattern of using the $appPool's object when I need to supply it the $appPools name which is just $app. When I switched that it worked.